# How to convert hexadecimal date value in sqlserver to corresponding data format in sparksql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Getting this **0x00EF290000000000** hexadecimal value from one of the column in sqlserver database.

How to convert this hexadecimal value to data value using spark?

Need to show its corresponding datetime value.

Answer (score 0):

below the way that i tried to convert a timestamp to hex and back to timestamp

```
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List("2009-07-30 12:58:59")).toDF("col1")

df.withColumn("hex_timestamp1", hex($"col1")).withColumn("timestamp2", decode(unhex($"hex_timestamp1"),"UTF-8")).show()

Output:
+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|               col1|      hex_timestamp1|         timestamp2|
+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|2009-07-30 12:58:59|323030392D30372D3...|2009-07-30 12:58:59|
+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

this might be useful!